# Is it possible to use If/Then Statements with dynamic text in Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, data-driven-pages, dynamic

Is it possible to use If/Then statements with dynamic text in Data Driven pages labeling?
I have been trying a bunch of different ways, but it has not been working, and I am fairly new at writing scripts.

If I was to write out my statement in a label expression, my example would be:

```
Function FindLabel([Land_Owner_Zone1], [Land_Owner_Zone2], [Zone])
If [zone] = "Zone 1" Then
Findlabel = [Land_Owner_Zone1] & vbnewline & [Zone]
Else
Findlabel = [Land_Owner_Zone2] & vbnewline & [Zone]
End If
End Function
```

I am unsure how to write this in dynamic text format for data driven pages.